# Can I detach inner std::future thread?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider following code:

```
template <typename func_t, typename ... Args>
auto waiter (func_t func, const Args &... args) -> decltype(func(args...)) {
  const static std::chrono::milliseconds max_time(10);
  auto task = std::packaged_task<decltype(func(args...))()>(std::bind(func, args...));
  auto handle = task.get_future();
  std::thread th(std::move(task)); // here
  if (handle.wait_for(max_time) == std::future_status::timeout) {
    th.detach(); // and here
    throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
  } else { // and here
    th.detach();
    return handle.get();
  }
}
```

Can I safely take inner `std::thread` from `std::future` and detach it? I guess it's obvious UB. `waiter()` function is designed to take any callable object, call it and stop work if any of

1. timeout reached
2. function stop it's work and return result

is true. I tried to do this in many ways, but there is always a problem. I realized that the problem is C++14 don't have process support.
First attempt:

```
template <typename func_t, typename ... Args>
auto waiter (func_t func, const Args &... args) -> decltype(func(args...)) {
  const static std::chrono::milliseconds max_time(10);
  decltype(func(args...)) result;
  std::mutex mtx;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  std::condition_variable cv;

  thread th([&] {
      result = func(args...);
      cv.notify_all();
  });

  auto waiting_result = cv.wait_for(lock, max_time);
  th.detach();
  if (waiting_result == std::cv_status::timeout) {
    throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
  }
  return result;
}
```

The problem here is after throwing exception, `std::thread` `th` is still running with killed references. Second attempt:

```
template <typename func_t, typename ... Args>
auto waiter (func_t func, const Args &... args) ->     decltype(func(args...)) {
  const static std::chrono::milliseconds max_time(10);
  auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async, func, args ...);
  if (handle.wait_for(max_time) == std::future_status::timeout) {
    throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
  } else {
    return handle.get();
  }
}
```

Here the problem is (as far I understand) that `std::async::~async()` calls some kind of `std::thread::join()` on it's inner thread and the main thread is still waiting for `std::async`. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Cyd2hYJCQSIxETqL
Silly one.

Answer (score 1):

You can detach the thread like you did in your first attempt, but then, as you say, the thread will keep running detached until it finishes on its own.

The problem with the second attempt is that the `std::future` returned by `std::async` is kind of special as its destructor will [**block until the thread finishes execution**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23455104/873025) (unlike the destructor of a regular `std::future`)

I'm afraid that in C++ it's not possible to safely terminate a single thread without killing all threads. The problem arises from the difficulty of safely unwinding the stack at an arbitrary point during execution. If let's say, the unwinding should take place in an inappropriate place like a ctor or dtor, it would break the rules of object-storage duration.

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12207684/873025) for more details.