# Why std::future not blocking

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using VS2013.
I just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455104/why-is-the-destructor-of-a-future-returned-from-stdasync-blocking) and found that a future should block in its destructor.

I tried some code but the `std::future` did not block.

```
void PrintFoo()
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    {
        auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, PrintFoo);
    }
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        std::cout << "Waiting" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Before application end" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have the output:

```
Foo
Waiting
Foo
Waiting
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: VS2017 does not reproduce this behavior. It just keeps printing `Foo`, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your braces around `f` introduce a new scope, and because `f` is defined in that scope, it will get destroyed when that scope ends. Which is immediately after, and `f` will then block. So technically, it should print `Foo` every second.

The actual output is more interesting though. Your compiler interleaves the two infinite loops, which [it isn't allowed to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x) (because your loop has side effects) since C++11 (I guess VS2013 isn't fully C++11 standards compliant yet).

Comment: But that loop *"makes calls to library I/O functions"*, so it should not assume that the loop should terminate...

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh right. Maybe VS2013 doesn't actually implement that part...