# boost::future::then() not returning future that blocks on destruction

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I wrote this sample code to test `boost::future` continuations to use in my application.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <exception>

#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE
#define BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_FUTURE_CONTINUATION

#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

void magicNumber(std::shared_ptr<boost::promise<long>> p)
{
    sleep(5);
    p->set_value(0xcafebabe);
}

boost::future<long> foo()
{
    std::shared_ptr<boost::promise<long>> p = 
    std::make_shared<boost::promise<long>>();

    boost::future<long> f = p->get_future();

    boost::thread t([p](){magicNumber(p);});

    t.detach();

    return f;
}

void bar()
{
    auto f = foo();
    f.then([](boost::future<long> f) { std::cout << f.get() << std::endl; });
    std::cout << "Should have blocked?" << std::endl; 
}

int main()
{   
    bar();

    sleep (6);

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled, linked and run with boost version 1.64.0_1, I am getting following output:

```
Should have blocked?
3405691582
```

But according to `boost::future::then`'s documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.unique_future.then).
The execution should be blocked at `f.then()` in function `bar()` because the temporary variable of type `boost::future<void>` should block at destruction, and the output should be

```
3405691582
Should have blocked?
```

In my application though, the call to `f.then()` is blocking the execution till continuation is not invoked.
What is happening here?

Comment: I'm curios - is the boost usage a must? I was able to do the same using only standard features https://gist.github.com/artemyv/baab7c8c74bb7fde07ebdcf2aee19881

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky No, implementing the same functionality is a no-issue here. The question is barely out of curiosity. Also, using .then seems better in terms of composability instead of using if-else. You would realise the same behaviour happens in case of futures created by std::async, they block on destruction, which should have happened here, and it happens in my application code as well. My question is why it is not happening in this case. Or is it reproducible by others as well. Thanks, for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the only time a future would ever block in the destructor used to be documented as when you use `std::async` with a launch-policy of `launch::async`.

See [Why is the destructor of a future returned from `std::async` blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455104/why-is-the-destructor-of-a-future-returned-from-stdasync-blocking)

The answer lists the many discussions that have taken place around this subject. The proposal [N3776](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3776.pdf) made it into C++14:

> *This paper provides proposed wording to implement a positive SG1 straw poll to clarify that `~future` and
>   `~shared_future` don’t block except possibly in the presence of async.*

cppreference.com documents [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

[image]

Your code never used async, so it would be surprising if any future derived *would* block on destruction.

More gener
ally, it is clear that the consensus is that blocking destruction is an unfortunate design wart, not something you'd expect being introduced on newer extensions (such as `.then` continuations).

I can only assume this is a case of documentation error where the wording

> - The returned futures behave as the ones returned from boost::async, the destructor of the future object returned from then will block. This could be subject to change in future versions.

should be removed.