# std::thread that isn't a global variable but doesn't go out of scope when the end of the function that created it is reached?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

So I ran across something that seems to defeat the purpose of `std::thread` or at least makes it less convenient.

Say I want to spawn an `std::thread` to perform a task one time and don't want to worry about it again after that. I create this `thread` near the end of a function so the `std::thread` will soon go out of scope, in my case, likely while the `thread` is still running. This creates a problem with a couple of solutions (or at least that I know of).

I can:

A) Make the `std::thread` a global variable so it doesn't go out of scope.

B) Call `join()` on the `std::thread` which defeats the purpose of spawning the thread.

Are there other, hopefully better, ways to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: If you don't care about the task, why launch it in the first place?

Comment: What's the problem with the `std::thread` object being destroyed? It's as much the thread as a `std::fstream` is the file, they are both just handles to a resource, not the resource itself. Also, why does it matter that it's a `std::thread` and how would you do it with a different kind of object, say `std::string`?

Comment: @Ulrich read the [fine manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread).

Comment: I'm aware of possible problems @n.m., but the description is simply lacking and that's important to pick the right approach.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt From what I understand calling the destructor of an `std::thread` before calling `join()` or `detach()` causes `terminate()` to be called on the thread which ends it forcefully. An `std::string` isn't exactly comparable to a thread because the thread is running a separate task. A string is a piece of data. I'm not quite sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @n.m. The task simply iterates through an array of classes and assigns one member variable in each to a specific value. However, the array is large enough that this task takes some time which is why I use a separate thread. This is a pretty simple task that doesn't really entail any exceptions or a meaningful return value which is why I just want to spawn the thread and leave it be. Not so much that I don't care, just that there's nothing more needed than starting the thread.

Comment: The problem here is that you never know when the task finishes, or whether it finishes at all. So your program may terminate even before your thread starts doing its work. This approach is mostly good for tasks that are optional. In addition, if your task modifies global data without any synchronisation, you open yourself to all kinds of nasty consequences.

Comment: This seems more like a lack in understanding of the language then anything specific to std::thread. There are a lot of options other then local variable in the function and a global. A simple thread pool or task system need not be more then 20 lines of code and can be reused in the future.

Comment: @super I can't know what I don't know, ya know? You are correct, it is purely out of ignorance of certain features and methods which I addressed: `This creates a problem with a couple of solutions (or at least that I know of).` I haven't done much with multi-threading except some projects that were done in free time and for fun. I've never done C++ in what I would call a "professional environment".

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen Ofcourse. I'm only trying to say that I think it's better to leave the multithreading aspect out of how you manage object lifetime. All you are looking for is somewhere to store your thread object. It could be any object, and managing it's lifetime is something you deal with even if threads are not involved. Break problems down to smaller parts.

Comment: Destroying the `std::thread` "causes terminate() to be called on the thread" is not the case, it "causes terminate() to be called", terminating your process.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Noted. Thank you for clearing up my misconception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is [std::thread::detach](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach).

It decouples the actual thread of execution and the `std::thread` object, allowing you to destroy it without joining the threads.

Comment: You have to be careful with detached threads. How do you handle exceptions? How do know/control if the thread is running or has finished?

Comment: @AchimGuetlein `std::thread`s are terminated if the exception is thrown, regardless of whether they are detached or not. To communicate with the thread you have all the usual mechanics - `std::future`, `std::mutex`, atomics etc - again, they don't depend on the `std::thread` object

Comment: you are right. There are ways to handle all these problems. My point was that if you don't address these problems, you might get into troubles. And if you do, it might be simpler to use the `std::future` returned by `std::async`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::async`.

[async](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) runs the function f asynchronously (potentially in a separate thread which may be part of a thread pool) and returns a std::future that will eventually hold the result of that function call.

Since you did not mention that you need to get the result of the thread, there is no need to get the future.

As pointed out in the comments, the destructor of std::future will block in any case, so you will have to move it to some global object (and manually manage deletion of unused futures), or you can move it into the local scope of the asynchronously called function.

Comment: He did not mention that he wants to get the result of the thread. So no need to get the future.

Comment: But what if the return value of async is not assigned to a future?

Comment: @P.W also blocks, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23455104/why-is-the-destructor-of-a-future-returned-from-stdasync-blocking)

Comment: The return value of `std::async` *is* `std::future`, and its destructor will block.

Answer (score 1):

Other preferred option is to allow the thread to consume tasks from a task-queue. For that, split the job into task chuncks and feed to the worker thread. To avoid polling, opt for condition_variable.

```
std::thread([&](){
                    while(running) // thread loop
                    { 
                       // consume tasks from queue
                    }
                 }).detach();
```