# How to store self-removing futures in a list

Tags: c++, c++17, future

I have some tasks that need to be performed asynchronously, and the server can't close while there are still tasks running. So I'm trying to store the futures returned by `std::async` in a list, but I also don't want to get an infinitely growing list of those. So I want to remove the futures as they're completed.

Here's roughly what I'm trying to do:

```
// this is a member of the server class
std::list<std::future<void>> pending;

std::list<std::future<void>>::iterator iter = ???;

pending.push_back( std::async( std::launch::async, [iter]()
{
    doSomething();
    pending.remove( iter );
} );
```

Here, `iter` needs to be pointing to the newly inserted element, but I can't get it before inserting the element (there is no iterator), nor after (since it is passed to the lambda by value). I could make a `shared_ptr` to store the iterator, but that seems to be way overkill.

Is there a better pattern for this?

**Update:** there seems to be another issue with this. When a future attempts to remove itself from the list, it is essentially waiting for itself to complete, which locks everything up. Oops!

On top of that, list destructor empties the list *before* calling element destructors.

Comment: Are you aware that this code anyway will require some kind of synchronization, like mutex?

Comment: You mean for `remove`? Yes, I'll need something like that. The push operation is only called from socket listener so that should be synchronized already.

Comment: I'd be careful with that. C++ memory model does not guarantee visibility of changes between threads without memory fences

Comment: Oh right, I will need to sync the pushes with removes anyway so might as well put a mutex everywhere.

Comment: Or use lockfree list, whatever works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the C++ 11 way to fire off an asynchronous task and forget about it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454793/whats-the-c-11-way-to-fire-off-an-asynchronous-task-and-forget-about-it)

Comment: I don't want to forget about it though, because the server needs to wait for tasks to be done before closing. It could be done via some counters/conditions, but it seems std::async was made exactly to avoid going through all this trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears you can just append a default `std::future` to the list, get an iterator to that and then **move** your future in.

Mind you, that non-mutex-protected `remove(iter)` looks awfully dangerous.

Comment: Not only `remove`, the `push_back` need to be synchronized as well.

Comment: @DanielLangr: That is one solution. The other is to drop the idea that futures remove themselves, and instead have the same thread do the push_back and the erase.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, is it even possible for a future to remove itself from the list? Wouldn't it lock everything up, since it will be waiting for itself to complete?

Comment: @riv: Have you checked if there's already a StackOverflow question about that? Because it is a good question, and shouldn't be buried in a comment.

Comment: I'm trying to see what happens for myself and I'm getting a runtime error saying iterator can't be incremented, so once I figure out what that means I might ask a question.

Comment: Oh, that's because in my example the list itself is emptied (due to going out of scope) before the elements are destroyed. That seems to be a problem.

Comment: @riv: Seeing your comment on a deleted answer, why bother removing the futures from the list at all? As the list is going out of scope anyway, the contents do not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. I don't think this one needs futures:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

struct server
{
    std::mutex pending_mutex;
    std::condition_variable pending_condition;
    std::unordered_set<unsigned> pending;
    unsigned next_id =  0;

    void add_task()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(pending_mutex);
        auto id = next_id++;
        auto t = std::thread([this, id]{
            this->doSomething();
            this->notify_complete(id);
        });
        t.detach(); // or we could store it somewhere. e.g. pending could be a map
        pending.insert(id);
    }

    void doSomething();

    void notify_complete(unsigned id)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(pending_mutex);
        pending.erase(id);
        if (pending.empty())
            pending_condition.notify_all();
    }

    void wait_all_complete()
    {
        auto none_left = [&] { return pending.empty(); };

        auto lock = std::unique_lock(pending_mutex);
        pending_condition.wait(lock, none_left);
    }
};


int main()
{
    auto s = server();
    s.add_task();
    s.add_task();
    s.add_task();
    s.wait_all_complete();
}
```

Here it is with futures, in case that's important:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

struct server
{
    std::mutex pending_mutex;
    std::condition_variable pending_condition;
    std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::future<void>> pending;
    unsigned next_id =  0;

    void add_task()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(pending_mutex);
        auto id = next_id++;
        auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, [this, id]{
            this->doSomething();
            this->notify_complete(id);
        });
        pending.emplace(id, std::move(f));
    }

    void doSomething();

    void notify_complete(unsigned id)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(pending_mutex);
        pending.erase(id);
        if (pending.empty())
            pending_condition.notify_all();
    }

    void wait_all_complete()
    {
        auto none_left = [&] { return pending.empty(); };

        auto lock = std::unique_lock(pending_mutex);
        pending_condition.wait(lock, none_left);
    }
};


int main()
{
    auto s = server();
    s.add_task();
    s.add_task();
    s.add_task();
    s.wait_all_complete();
}
```

Here's the list version:

```
#include <list>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

struct server
{
    using pending_list = std::list<std::future<void>>;
    using id_type = pending_list::const_iterator;

    std::mutex pending_mutex;
    std::condition_variable pending_condition;
    pending_list pending;

    void add_task()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(pending_mutex);

        // redundant construction
        auto id = pending.emplace(pending.end());
        auto f = std::async(std::launch::async, [this, id]{
            this->doSomething();
            this->notify_complete(id);
        });
        *id = std::move(f);
    }

    void doSomething();

    void notify_complete(id_type id)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(pending_mutex);
        pending.erase(id);
        if (pending.empty())
            pending_condition.notify_all();
    }

    void wait_all_complete()
    {
        auto none_left = [&] { return pending.empty(); };

        auto lock = std::unique_lock(pending_mutex);
        pending_condition.wait(lock, none_left);
    }
};


int main()
{
    auto s = server();
    s.add_task();
    s.add_task();
    s.add_task();
    s.wait_all_complete();
}
```

Comment: The second version is roughly the same as what I'm trying to do, except it uses a map instead of list, which I figured is unnecessary since IDs are meaningless to me so might as well use iterators.

Comment: Sure you could use a list. Although the overhead of using a map is minimal. You'd need to default construct the map entry and the. Move the future in. This might require some exception handling for completeness. I find the map solution to be very maintainable and flexible in the real world. Pay your money, take your choice. :)

Comment: @riv added a list version for completeness.